# C++ issue about members of a class

Tags: c++, member

I implemented this code to learn members of a class in C++. I am getting errors:

> [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'int'
>
> [Error] expected ')' before 'int'

on line 4 of the code

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shubh(int a, int b )

:regVar(a) , constVar(b)

{ 
           public:
        Shubh();
        void print()
               {
        cout<<"Reg var is"<<regVar<<"const var is"<<constVar<<endl;


           }

                private:
        int regVar;
        const int constVar;


};

int main(){

    Shubh ObjShubh(3,87);
    ObjShubh.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There seems to be some very basic misunderstandings about how to define classes. Please try to go through your class-notes again, and read through your text-book again.

Comment: Please see [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm) to learn how to use Initialization Lists.

Comment: Why do you indent your code like this?

Answer (score 4):

You combined your class definition with your constructor definition, resulting in an ill-defined program. I believe your intention was

```
// Class definition
class Shubh
{ 
public:
    // Constructor definition
    Shubh(int a, int b) : regVar(a) , constVar(b) {}

    void print()
    {
        cout<<"Reg var is"<<regVar<<"const var is"<<constVar<<endl;
    }
private:
    int regVar;
    const int constVar;
};
```